# Вывести количество обращений к каждому домену на awk

Tags: bash, awk

У меня есть задача вывести все домены 2-го уровня net. (с этим я разобрался).
Но остановился на том, что мне нужно вывести ко-во обращений к этому домену и не знаю как это сделать.
Пытаюсь разобраться с ассоциативным массивом awk, но пока что не даётся
На данный момент у меня получается следующее:

```
BEGIN
{
/[a-z]\.net/{print tolower($15)} /home/user/lab1/dns-tunneling.log| sort

}
END
{print"END."}
```

В моём представлении массив получается так

```
BEGIN
{
myarr[NR]=$15
for(i in myarr)
{
if(myarr[i]==myarr[i+1])
count++
}
}
END
{
print "END"
}
```

или так

```
BEGIN
{
myarr[NR]=$15
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
if($i==$i+1)
count++
}
}
END
{
print "END"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22800531/4827341

Comment: Этот вариант я пробовал stackoverflow.com/q/22800531/4827341.
Мне нужно с уже отсортированного файла с моими доменами вывести к какому домену сколько раз подключаются.

Answer (score 0):

В общем у получилось следующее:

1. Сохраняем все результаты сортировки по маске в файл (в моём случае я его назвал как script)

```
awk '[a-z]\.net/{print tolower($15)}' /home/user/lab1/dns-tunneling.log | sort >script
```

2. Теперь полученные результаты берём из файла и проходимся массивом по ним

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{arr[$NF]++} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i] | "sort"}' /home/user/lab1/script
```